# Comprobar que una variable existe JAVA

Tags: java, xml, parser

estoy recogiendo datos de un XML y necesito comprobar si ese dato se ha recogido, es decir, si existe. Os dejo el código

```
Node estimatedOverallContractAmountNode = budgetAmount.getElementsByTagName("cbc:EstimatedOverallContractAmount").item(0);
double estimatedOverallContractAmount = Double.parseDouble(estimatedOverallContractAmountNode.getTextContent());
String estimatedOverallContractAmountCurrencyID = estimatedOverallContractAmountNode.getAttributes().getNamedItem("currencyID").getTextContent();

//Aqui debo hacer la comprobacion y lo intento hacer de la siguiente manera:
if (estimatedOverallContractAmount) {
   hacer_algo();
}
```

Obviamente, esta forma no me funciona. El valor es un double, no quiero comprobar su contenido, SOLO si se ha podido recoger satisfactoriamente o no. Otra cuestión es que si ese campo no existe en el XML, me salta una excepción, y a mi me gustaría que, en ese caso, la variable se pusiese a NULL. ¿Sería esto posible? Gracias, un saludo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
double estimatedOverallContractAmount
```

`estimatedOverallContractAmount` es una primitiva. Hay un espacio de memoria reservado para el valor, el valor siempre existirá (aunque pueda ser 0.0).

```
if (estimatedOverallContractAmount) {
```

A diferencia de otros lenguajes (C/C++), `if` y `while` espera una expresión booleana. En C te comprobaria si `estimatedOverallContractAmount` se evalúa a 0 (false) o no (true), en Java `estimatedOverallContractAmount` debería ser `true` o `false`.

El equivalente en Java sería

```
if (estimatedOverallContractAmount != 0d) {
```

que es una expresión que es `true` o `false`.

En todo caso,

```
double estimatedOverallContractAmount = Double.parseDouble(estimatedOverallContractAmountNode.getTextContent());
```

Si aquí `estimatedOverallContractAmountNode.getTextContent()` devuelve `null` o la cadena vacía, te saltará una excepción porque no se puede parsear como `double` (recordemos, es una primitiva, no hay valor `null`). Este es el valor que tienes que controlar, antes de hacer ninguna conversión.

```
if ((estimatedOverallContractAmountNode.getTextContent() != null) && !estimatedOverallContractAmountNode.getTextContent().isBlank()) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Realmente no tienes que hacer la comprobación: [`Double.parseDouble`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble(java.lang.String)) lanzará una excepción si el parámetro es `null` o no tiene un `String` que se pueda interpretar como un número válido:

```
try {
    double estimatedOverallContractAmount = Double.parseDouble(estimatedOverallContractAmountNode.getTextContent());
} catch (Exception e) {
    //no existe el valor
}
```